# Plugin implementation issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've been having a problem implementing a plugin which is supposed to be "simple". The plugin is at this address : http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

I tried testing it out with a simple short code and checked the code from the page where the plugin is displayed to make sure I was doing it right, but apparently nothing happens and I'm not getting any errors feedback so I don't know what direction to go towards.

Here be the code I test ran it with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test#0935</title>

        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load jQuery 
            google.load("jquery", "1"); 
        </script>
        <script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("a").bind("click",function(){
                $("#flipo").flip({
                    direction: "tb"
                })
                return false;
            });

        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

            #flipo {
                width:100px;
                height:70px;
                background-color:lightblue;
                margin:20px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="flipo"></div>
        <a href="#" id="left">left</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

I "imported" the same source for the jQuery library as the plugin-author did and I've made sure the reference to the plugin is correct.

Looking at the source code for the authors page, you see that he too "binds" a click function on link tags, calls the .flip method from his plugin, and "tb" means "flip leftwards".

Comment: Eeek, `bind()`! Should be using `.on()` these days.

Comment: thanks! Ill keep note of it. I'm still new to a lot of things x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `.bind()` in a `$(function() {});` wrapper. This simulates [`$(document).ready()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29), which means that "everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded. "

```
$(function() {
    $("a").bind("click",function(){
        $("#flipo").flip({
            direction: "tb"
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ach, didnt think of that one. My bad, thanks! I'll give it a shot right now.

Comment: Yes my box flipped ! wrong direction, but still, it works =) Im sorry for my dumb mistake as I had rushed my code to test it out and of course forgot the most important, I hadn't even coded the JS document ready command.. I had a rushed course of JS recently, just started with jQ and I must admit I'm still mixing lots of things together, forgetting important stuff, plus I have to hand in a complete web site soon so stress increases errors. Thanks again!! =)

Comment: @KizerYakuza I wouldn't say it's a dumb mistake, it's a common one. Glad it worked. If I answered your question fully, please mark it as "answered". Good luck!

Comment: Could I quickly ask some clarification on the bind method because I was under the impression that jQuery syntax "did it" automatically, binding an action to a specific selector or is it just the way in which this plugin was written that requires it? I'm doubly curious because I hadn't come across that command before. For me it was JS which required more manual binding.

Comment: (and I had clicked on accept answer but I still had to wait a certain amount of time before clicking it =))

Comment: @KizerYakuza I suggest reading the jQuery documentation, it has a lot of the answers you are looking for. http://api.jquery.com/bind/ And as someone suggested up top, read the documentation for `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: nooo .. i've come across another problem. My problem is I have no clue what the source of it might be. I've manage to "loose" the second half of the flip animation, it just invisible instead of showing the end of the flip anim. I had tweaked a bit with the plugin source code, but deleted that file and even downloaded a fresh copy to make sure. I've simplified my code again to just test it on one box through a link element. Could someone please test out the flip plugin if they have time and tell me if they get the "full rotation"? i'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: @KizerYakuza No one is looking at this comment thread anymore but you and I; I suggest you post your new problem as a new question, you'll get better answers that way!

Comment: thanks! I was thinking the same and was about to just edit the whole post as my issue is more or less the same, given the same code and plugin. Hopefully that'll work ^^

Comment: @KizerYakuza Nope, you're better off posting it as a brand new question. My suggestion is that you revert to the original question, post a new question, and just link to this one. That's probably the fastest way for you to get an answer.

Comment: thanks again for the follow up ! =) I did start a new post and managed to get things sorted x) the other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751099/javascript-jquery-plugin-rendering-problems#