# Javascript jQuery plugin rendering problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Here is my problem. There's a nifty looking plugin here http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ which flips things around. I managed to implement it, but for some odd reason I'm only getting the first half of the animation rendered, the second part is just invisible (or hidden) and then it jumps to the end. To make things even more fun, everything was working fine at some point but then suddenly not. I of course backtracked as far back as possible back to when things were fine, and same problem again. I can't seem to locate the source of the problem. If someone could just please help me out by testing out the plugin and telling me if they managed to get a full animation rendered. For my HTML I based it on the source code of the plugin demo page to make sure, but to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test#0935</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load jQuery 
        google.load("jquery", "1");
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.flip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#id1").bind("click", function() {
                $("#flipo").flip({
                    direction: "bt"
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #flipo {
            width:100px;
            height:70px;
            background-color:lightblue;
            margin:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flipo"></div>
    <div id="id1">left</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For those of you who recognize this problem, I did try to avoid posting a new thread until I was advised to do so as no one was reading the old post. I've also flagged my initial post for deletion.

Comment: Would it be possible to have your code in the form of a Codepen or JSfiddle? That'd be a great help in figuring out where the issue is.

Comment: @NickTomlin as soon as I figure either one out x) I'll give fiddle a go! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the basics of what you posted, I set up a quick fiddle and it worked fine, but that was when I noticed that you have not included your JS correctly. I think the issue is with that.

First you are pulling in jQuery from google using `google.load`. Then you are getting a (potentially different) version from jQuery.com. Also, flip relies on jQuery UI, and I can't see you importing that anywhere in the html snippet you posted.

Why don't you try this and get rid of the google.load and jQuery.com sources and see if that works.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.flip.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I see what you meant with the potentially constrasting versions of jQ. I put it in because the plugin's author had done the same at http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ which works. I tried without the google library inclusion, just using the jQ library found at jquery.com but I had the same results. And also, of course, jQ UI I didn't even know about I'm ashamed to say :p - Our class was kinda slow at learning JS so we ended up rushing through jQ this past week. Btw, I love this site, as soon as I know more JS/jQ I'll contribute as much help as possible x)

Comment: (btw, I always include the @-name- at the start of my comments but they dont always take..)  -  this particular msg is without any @

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/BSWeY/)

This plugin depend's on `jquery` and `jqueryUI`,  include both in your code

Comment: Really? I just tested it with 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2 and it worked fine...

Comment: hmm .. i just tested that.. it works

Comment: Thanks for the input x) Im kinda stressed out juggling all these new and obscure commands and methods =)